# how to list data according to date using jquery or jquery mobile mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-mobile

I'm developing a library mobile application using jquery mobile and asp.net  I'm new to jquery mobile  and I'm facing an issue and I don't have the slightest idea about the solution I need to display books arrival according to the date in my page  the date will  be the title and below the thumbnails of books will display like displayed below
 [image]

I don't except the code for this solution I just need little ideas for solving  this problem

NB: Json Parsing and Html formatting are my prime goals

Comment: What are you asking? HTML formatting? CSS? How to parse JSON?

Comment: @mplungjan mainley HTML formatting and Json Parse

Comment: The standard question here is then "What have you tried?" For example is the date today's date or comes in the JSON, in what format, what does the JSON look like

Comment: @mplungjan I tried The Accordions offered by the jquery mobile  but I don't want to collapse my data

Comment: 1) show us the JSON 2) show us some code that tries to format it. You are already looking at presentation but have not yet parsed the data. If you have <div><h3>date</h3><div>Data</div></div> you are already close to your goal

Comment: @optimus please share the code what have u tried right now?

Comment: @mplungjan <div><h3>date</h3><div>Data</div></div> Thats what I was missed I never thought that Thanks for your help my problem solved

Comment: Wow. That was about the minimum HTML I could think of

Comment: @mplungjan yeah I know I never thought about that some times we all forget the small things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this..
I have taken some sample json and displayed in a list view with date as header.

```
<div data-role=header>
    <h1>Home</h1>
  </div>
  <div data-role="content" id="home">
  </div>


var response=[
  {"date":"27/09/2013", 
   "books":["All Passion Spent", 
            "All the King's Men", 
            "An Acceptable Time", 
            "An Evil Cradling"]
  }, 
  {"date":"26/09/2013",
   "books":["Bury My Heart at Wounded Knee", 
            "Butter In a Lordly Dish", 
            "Clouds of Witness", 
            "Cover Her Face"]}
];

show_response(response);

function show_response(myobj){
     var ansString ='<div><ul data-role="listview" data-theme="c" data-inset="true"               data-dividertheme="b" >';
 $.each(myobj,function(index,quesobj){
   ansString = ansString+"<li data-role='list-divider'><h3>"+quesobj.date+"</h3></li>"   
   for(key in quesobj.books){    
        ansString = ansString+'<li><a href="#">'+quesobj.books[key]+'</a></li>'                         
     }     
  });
    ansString = ansString+"</ul></div>"
    $("#home").html(ansString).trigger("create");
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/YXLKw/3/

Comment: Please do not side step the SO rule of having to add the code in the answer. Link only answers lose their worth when the link becomes inactive. If the fiddle code is very length, you can post the essential parts alone here.

Comment: Thanks Harry..Modified

Comment: You have too many `</div>` and why $.each AND `for(key in quesobj.books)` please be consequent